# How to switch from Compass to Laravel Elixir

Tags: laravel, sass, compass-sass, compass, laravel-elixir

I've been using Compass to compile Sass in my project, but it is now deprecated and no longer maintained so I want to move away from using Compass. The project uses PHP and Laravel, so I would like to use Laravel Elixir for compiling the Sass files instead.

Is there a way to transfer my .scss files from Compass to Elixir without going in and changing all the places in my Sass code that I use Compass helpers, or do I need to more or less re-write my Sass files? There are a ton of them, so I would love to avoid that.

On the suggestion of my co-worker, what I tried was to add the compass files to my `resources/assets/sass` directory (includes `compass/css3`, `compass/layout`, `compass/reset`, `compass/typography`, and `compass/utilities`, as well as several other .scss files included in Compass. The hope was that by including these files, the functions of Compass would still apply outside of it.

When I try to compile with gulp, the error I'm currently getting (although I'm guess I'll run into another one once this is fixed) is:

```
>> Sass Compilation Failed: resources/assets/sass/compass/_support.scss
Error: Undefined operation: "prefix-usage(browser-prefixes(browsers()), css-transitions, (full-support: true), (partial-support: true)) gt 0.1".
        on line 324 of resources/assets/sass/compass/_support.scss
>>   @if $usage > $threshold {
   ------^
```

My guess is that I will need to go ahead and remove the Compass stuff from the Sass code manually, but I'm hoping someone else has a better solution for me! Thanks.